# Cannot run 'cmd' command with parameters 'sc sdshow w32time'

Tags: java, cmd, exec

I am trying to run an external process in Java and I have no idea why my code isn't working. It works for any other 'cmd' command (for example /c dir). If I replace `cmd sc sdshow w32time` with `cmd /c dir` it works.

Here is my code:

```
public class services2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd sc sdshow w32time");
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: does whatever account you're running this code under have the rights to run that command?

Comment: I have no idea what "cmd sc sdshow w32time" actually does but I do know that if you remove "cmd" from the string you get output just fine.

Comment: Well, running `cmd` in Windows forks off a new 'shell', afaik. So the next part of the command string should be an executable. You probably want to 1) Supply the full path of the executable (sc) 2) Split your command string up (eg `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd", "drive:\path\to\sc", "sdshow", "w32time");`).

Comment: Why are you omitting the `/c` for your `sc` command, but applying it to your `dir` command?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that `sc` is not an argument for `cmd`.
What you need is:

`sc sdshow w32time`